# scalaの抽象クラスのパターンマッチの方法

Tags: scala

```
abstract class A

case class AA(s: String) extends A

abstract class AB(n: Int) extends A

case class ABA(n: Int) extends AB(n)
case class ABB(n: Int) extends AB(n)

object Main extends App {
    val list: List[A] = List(AA("aa"), ABA(12), ABB(34))
    for(a <- list) {
        a match {
            case AA(s) => println("AA:" + s)
            case AB(n) => println("AB:" + n)
        }
    }
}
```

このようなパターンマッチを書くには、どのようなunapplyを定義すれば良いのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`abstract class AB`が`n`というメンバーないしメソッドを持っていることを意図されているのであれば、`AB`を下記のように定義し、そのコンパニオンオブジェクト`object AB`に`unapply`を定義すればよいかと思います。

※AとBが多く見辛かったので、`ABA`を`AB1`、`ABB`を`AB2`に変えています

```
abstract class A

case class AA(s: String) extends A

abstract class AB extends A {
  def n: Int
}
object AB {
  def unapply(ab: AB): Option[Int] = Option(ab).map(_.n)
}

case class AB1(n: Int) extends AB
case class AB2(n: Int) extends AB

object Main extends App {
  for (a <- List[A](AA("aa"), AB1(12), AB2(34))) {
    a match {
      case AA(s) => println("AA:" + s)
      case AB(n) => println("AB:" + n)
    }
  }
}
```

abstract classである必要がなければ、traitでも構いません。

```
trait A

case class AA(s: String) extends A

trait AB extends A {
  def n: Int
}
object AB {
  def unapply(ab: AB): Option[Int] = Option(ab).map(_.n)
}

case class AB1(n: Int) extends AB
case class AB2(n: Int) extends AB
```

---

英語版stackoverflowで類似する質問への回答もご参考ください。
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14810591/4366193